# Is there a variable width, non-breaking space in LaTeX

Tags: spacing

I sometimes use `~` in LaTeX to keep for example "Figure" together with its `\ref`. However, in some cases where LaTeX has to stretch a line quite a lot to fill it, it appears that `~` is fixed-width. It becomes much shorter than the other, unusually wide spaces on that line. Is there another character that achieves a non-breaking space but allows varying the width?

Comment: That means you have an underfull box. What you are looking for is available in Word and you know it is not a good idea ;) You might like `cleveref` package instead.

Comment: As Ulrike shows, `~` is stretchable. If it is not for you, then you need to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows the problem.

Comment: Word... :-) I know cleveref but cannot always use it due to journal requirements. BTW how does cleveref achieve non-breaking?

Answer (score 11):

`~` has not a fixed width, at least not with its default definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
ABC~ABC~ABC ABC ABC ABC\linebreak
blub
\end{document}
```

[image]